# How to prevent searching when users type even a letter?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have below form with input options and datalist no submit button. it is search bar that I created. I also have javaScript with onchange event to add href for option tags. The problem is, when users would like to search and type even a letter it starts searching. Users should fully type and than search engine should work. How do I prevent this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("[list='serv']").on("input propertychange", function() {
   window.location = $("#serv option[value='"+$("[list='serv']").val()+"']").find("a").attr("href")
   });
});
```

```html
<form class="search">
  <input type="text" name="exx" list="serv" id="example">
  <datalist id="serv">
        <option value="google"><a href="https://www.google.com">google </a></option>
        <option value="facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com">facebook</a></option>
    </datalist>
</form>
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] because the `change` event should only be fired when the value of the input element is committed, such as by pressing the enter key, selecting a value from a list of options, and the like.

Comment: The simplest possible solution is adding a search button.

Comment: What do you mean with fully typed? You have to specify that. However I think it's better when the search stars even the user is typing. This is a lot more user friendly. (All modern searches are searching or giving suggestion when you type)

Comment: if users even type "p" it starts searching. When user type product instead of p and push enter than it should start searching

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
document.getElementById("form").onSubmit=function(){
window.location.href = this.children[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('href');

}
```

```html
<form class="search" id="form">
  <input type="text" name="exx" list="serv" id="example">
  <input type="submit" style="display:none" value="Submit">
  <datalist id="serv">
        <option value="b"><a href="https://www.google.com">google </a></option>
        <option value="z"><a href="https://www.facebook.com">facebook</a></option>
    </datalist>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you for reply. But it did not work out in my case. href attribute doesn't work  . After that Url change to this www.mysite.com/test?exx=b

Comment: then what's your desired result?

Comment: it should be www.mysite.com/product?exx=b and www.mysite.com/service?exx=b

Comment: You are taking the href attribute from a servlet, right?

Comment: Then you are missing the action attribute then, add action="Servlet file name" to the form